# How to find all values that occur more than n/k times in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I'm pursuing the [Algorithms, Part I](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1) course on Coursera, and one of the interview questions (ungraded) is as follows:

> **Decimal dominants**. Given an array with n keys, design an algorithm to find all values that occur more than n/10 times. The expected
>   running time of your algorithm should be linear.

It has a hint:

> determine the (n/10)th largest key using quickselect and check if it
>   occurs more than n/10 times.

I don't understand what does the n/10 largest key have to do with n/10 repeated values. It won't tell me which values occur more than n/10 times.

There's a [paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0167642382900120/1-s2.0-0167642382900120-main.pdf?_tid=e9b63ea4-6df0-4d84-b3fe-d5a22301e2a0&acdnat=1527477191_c7e63434dcae83c5eef7d925082f653f) that finds a more general solution for n/k, but I'm having a hard time understanding the code in the paper.

One way to solve it is to sort the input array, and then make another pass counting the occurrence of each distinct value. That'll take O(nlogn) + O(n) time, which is more than what the question asks for.

Ideas?

Comment: When the hint refers to being linear is means you are indexing through the array once.  If you where going to sort the array from largest to smallest it would take N^2.  There may be duplicates of each number in the array.  Each unique number in the array is the key.  So the question implies you have a Dictionary (an array with keys) and you need to search the dictionary for keys that have more than 10 items.

Comment: @jdweng A dictionary or hash table hasn't been introduced in the course yet, so such a data structure can't be used. Also, as I said in my question, there are faster sorting algorithms available than n^2.

Comment: You are right. Decimal dominant is among the next candidates after QuickSelect: `n/10, 2*n/10..9*n/10`, so checking only n/10 is not sufficient

Comment: @MBo please elaborate, didn't follow.

Comment: If an element occurs more than n/k times, then it must be at position i*n/k for some i in the range 0 to n/k in the sorted array. (If it is not at any of those positions, there cannot be n/k copies of the element because there is no room for n/k copies between two consecutive tested positions.) Quickselect can find each of those positions in time O(n), so finding all of them takes O(kn), which is O(n) if K is a known constant. But the generalised [Boyer-Moore majority algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm) is probably faster and easier to code.

Comment: But keys are referenced.   You are given the List<keys> and List<integers>.  So the algorithm is simply a counting task.

Comment: @jdweng if you’ve a solution in mind, don’t hold back, post it

Comment: If you have a range of number from 0 to 99 you know the index of each number.  So your 1st array is simply and array of 100 numbers with an initial value of zero.  Then if you have an 2nd array of random numbers from 0 to 99 you can easily count the occurrence of each number using a linear algorithm by simply using the 1st array.  Simply add one to the index of the array for each number in the random array.

Comment: @jdweng: I think you're misinterpreting the problem. Nowhere does it say that you are given a list of keys. It says you are given an array of keys, nothing more. Of course, I might be wrong, too: I'm not going to enroll in Coursera to find out.

Comment: @rici Quick select can select the kth smallest element in linear time, but AFAIK, it doesn't make any guarantees about equal elements being group contiguously. So I don't see how we would count the number of number of occurrences of n/k element without scanning the array again. The best I can think of if scanning from n/k till the end.

Comment: @abhijit: precisely. You find the `k` quantile points in the array, which you can do in O(nk) using QS `k` times. Now, any element which appears at least `n/k` times must cross a quantile, so it is sufficient to scan the entire array `k` times, each time counting the frequency of one quantile and recording the ones whose count is sufficiently high. (Again, O(nk), although since the quantiles are sorted, you could reduce the `k` to `log k` by doing one scan and binary searching each element in the list of quantiles. But since `k` is fixed, it's O(n) regardless.

Comment: ... if you got lucky, you might find the same element twice or more in the quantiles, which guarantees that that value is high frequency and saves you from having to do a scan for it. But you still have to scan for the other ones (if there are any). After the QS, the input data is partially sorted, so you don't really even need the binary search; you can do the whole thing with a single scan, checking each element against exactly two candidates. I'll leave you to figure out the details if you care to.

Answer (score 6):

Finding the n/10th largest key (that is, the key that would be at position n/10 if the array was sorted) takes linear time using QuickSelect. If there are less than n/10 copies of this key, then you know that there are not n/10 copies of anything above it in sorted order, because there isn't room for n/10 copies of anything above the key in sorted order. If there are n/10 or more copies, then you have found something that occurs more than n/10 times, and again there can't be anything larger than it that occurs more than n/10 times, because there isn't room for it.

Now you have an array of at most 9n/10 values smaller than the key you have just found left over from QuickSelect. Use another pass of QuickSelect to find the key n/10 from the top of this left over array. As before, you may find a key that occurs n/10 or more times, and whether you do or not you will eliminate at least n/10 entries from the array.

So you can search the whole array with 10 calls of QuickSelect, each taking linear time. 10 is a number fixed in the problem definition, so the whole operation counts as only linear time.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around the statement "If there are less than n/10 copies of this key, then you know that there are not n/10 copies of anything above it in sorted order". If we've `[6, 9, 7, 2, 5, 7, 7, 4]`, n = 8, k = 3, n/k = 2. The sorted array is `[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9]`, so the element at index 2 would be 5. Even though 5 occurs less than 2 times, there's 7 that occurs 3 times. How does the above statement hold?

Comment: I think your argument is backwards; as long as the n/k key is not decimal dominant, we need to recurse in the right subarray. Clearly, there can't be more than n/k keys of anything in the left subarray of n/k, otherwise it won't be in the position n/k. But we can't exclude the right subarray, so we need to keep looking until n/k < 0.

Comment: We are thinking about arrays sorted in different directions, and you also need to worry about special cases when n is not divisible by k. If you start by picking out the largest key think about sorting the array with the largest first so [9,7,7,7,6,5,4,2] and in fact you find 7.  For simplicity consider [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] and have n/k=3. If you use quickselect to find 7 you know that there are only 2 values greater than it and you only care about values that appear at least 3 times so you know you can ignore them.

Comment: @mcdowella, could you provide example?

Comment: @mcdowella lets imagine we have arrays of 100 elements. Let's consider tails of this array(biggest values) there ar 15 numbers with value = 8 and 9 and 10. So our arrays looks like: **[0,1,1,1,1,1.....7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,10]**. On the first step we investigate element with index 90(arr[90]) and start to compare it  with arr[91] -arr[99] and we calculate duplicates of arr[90]. So we get result 8(90-97).

Comment: @mcdowella the next element is arr[80]. arr[80] = 7 so we have to calculate duplicates of 7. So we missed elements with value = 8.  Does my understanding correct?

Comment: **Now you have an array of at most 9n/10 values smaller than the key you have just found left over from QuickSelect** - it is wrong. Actually smaller or equals

Comment: @gstackoverflow: He doesn't say that you just scan the partition for the boundary element. You scan the entire array (or whatever is left of it in each iteration). That's still O(n). (You can make this more efficient by doing all the partitions before you do the scans, in which case you only scan 2n/10 positions for each candidate. But that only changes the linear constant.)

Comment: @rici what you are saying seems to make sense, but I was actually assuming that if you were using QuickSelect to find frequent items near a given position, you would use what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements calls a "fat partition" variant which finds you all instances of the value it returns. I think this removes the difficulty encountered by gstackoverflow as well.

Comment: That would make sense, too, but you should really be explicit in the answer if that's what you meant. Most standard library select-nth functions aren't documented to do that, though, so unless you have a professor telling you to write it all from scratch, your best bet is to do k-1 QS's with the library function and the do the scan where you count each candidate in both the segment before and the segment after, watching out for duplicates. From a complexity analysis viewpoint it makes no difference if k is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

There is a variation of Boyer-Moore Voting algorithm which can find all the elements that occurs more than `n/k` in a input which runs in `O(nk)` and since `k = 10` for your problem I think it should run in `O(n * 10) = O(n)` time.

From [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-of-size-n-finds-all-the-elements-that-appear-more-than-nk-times/)

> Following is an interesting O(nk) solution: We can solve the above
>   problem in O(nk) time using O(k-1) extra space. Note that there can
>   never be more than k-1 elements in output (Why?). There are mainly
>   three steps in this algorithm.
>
> 1) Create a temporary array of size (k-1) to store elements and their
>   counts (The output elements are going to be among these k-1 elements).
>   Following is structure of temporary array elements.
>
> ```
>  struct eleCount {
>      int element;
>      int count; };  
>  struct eleCount temp[];  This step takes O(k) time.
> ```
>
> 2) Traverse through the input array and update temp[] (add/remove an
>   element or increase/decrease count) for every traversed element. The
>   array temp[] stores potential (k-1) candidates at every step. This
>   step takes O(nk) time.
>
> 3) Iterate through final (k-1) potential candidates (stored in
>   temp[]). or every element, check if it actually has count more than
>   n/k. This step takes O(nk) time.
>
> The main step is step 2, how to maintain (k-1) potential candidates at
>   every point? The steps used in step 2 are like famous game: Tetris. We
>   treat each number as a piece in Tetris, which falls down in our
>   temporary array temp[]. Our task is to try to keep the same number
>   stacked on the same column (count in temporary array is incremented).
>
> Consider k = 4, n = 9  Given array: 3 1 2 2 2 1 4 3 3
>
> i = 0
>
> ```
>      3 _ _ temp[] has one element, 3 with count 1
> ```
>
> i = 1
>
> ```
>      3 1 _ temp[] has two elements, 3 and 1 with  counts 1 and 1 respectively
> ```
>
> i = 2
>
> ```
>      3 1 2 temp[] has three elements, 3, 1 and 2 with counts as 1, 1 and 1 respectively.
> ```
>
> i = 3
>
> ```
>      - - 2 
>      3 1 2 temp[] has three elements, 3, 1 and 2 with counts as 1, 1 and 2 respectively.
> ```
>
> i = 4
>
> ```
>      - - 2 
>      - - 2 
>      3 1 2 temp[] has three elements, 3, 1 and 2 with counts as 1, 1 and 3 respectively.
> ```
>
> i = 5
>
> ```
>      - - 2 
>      - 1 2 
>      3 1 2 temp[] has three elements, 3, 1 and 2 with counts as 1, 2 and 3 respectively.
> ```
>
> Now the question arises, what to do when temp[]
>   is full and we see a new element – we remove the bottom row from
>   stacks of elements, i.e., we decrease count of every element by 1 in
>   temp[]. We ignore the current element.
>
> i = 6
>
> ```
>      - - 2 
>      - 1 2  temp[] has two elements, 1 and 2 with counts as 1 and 2 respectively.
> ```
>
> i = 7
>
> ```
>        - 2 
>      3 1 2  temp[] has three elements, 3, 1 and 2 with counts as 1, 1 and 2 respectively.
> ```
>
> i = 8
>
> ```
>      3 - 2
>      3 1 2  temp[] has three elements, 3, 1 and 2 with counts as 2, 1 and 2 respectively.
> ```
>
> Finally, we have at most k-1 numbers in
>   temp[]. The elements in temp are {3, 1, 2}. Note that the counts in
>   temp[] are useless now, the counts were needed only in step 2. Now we
>   need to check whether the actual counts of elements in temp[] are more
>   than n/k (9/4) or not. The elements 3 and 2 have counts more than 9/4.
>   So we print 3 and 2.

For a proper proof of this approach check out [this answer from cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/91803/explaination-for-variation-of-boyer-moore-majority-voting-algorithm)

Comment: geeksforgeeks is a dump site for any random Joe with an internet access, and I'd not put a dime on it. Thanks though.

Comment: The algorithm mentioned in that website answers your question if you still consider it a dump site it's up to you.

Comment: Questionable, at best, since the constant factor is small. Also, the code shown is basically a contrived lookup table with O(n) access time. If anyone uses this algorithm, they are much better off using a hash table, which as I specified in a comment on my original post, isn't allowed.

Comment: Hashtable approach uses `O(n)` space while this uses a constant space `O(k = 10)`

Comment: @abhijit: If there is a constraint to the problem, you should put it in the question, not a comment. SO comments are transitory. Also, this solution is most certainly viable, and it's similar to the proposal in the link you cite. So making an attempt to understand it rather than rejecting it out of hand will help you understand that paper.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

Decimal dominant is among the next candidates after QuickSelect: n/10, 2*n/10..9*n/10, so checking only n/10 index is not sufficient

Note that dominant occupies long run in sorted array and certainly at least one of elements with  mentioned  indexes belongs to that run.

Example for k = 3, N = 11. Let element b occupies at least 1/3 of array. In this case sorted array might look like

```
b b b b * * * * * * * 
* b b b b * * * * * * 
* * b b b b * * * * *     
* * * b b b b * * * *     
* * * * b b b b * * *
* * * * * b b b b * *
* * * * * b b b b * *
* * * * * * b b b b *
* * * * * * * b b b b
      ^       ^       //positions for quickselect
```

Note that in any case dominant element (if k-dominant does exist) occupies at least one of marked places. So after two rounds of QuickSelect we have two candidates

Comment: What's a candidate? Are you referring to the [Boyer–Moore majority vote algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm)? For an answer to an algo question, you should either lay out the solution idea, or provide pseudocode, or better, actual code. Sorry, but your answer adds nothing to your comment, and it appears to make assumptions not clearly stated (like reference to candidate).

Comment: Look at example for smaller k value

Comment: @gstackoverflow Look also at rici comments. What is not clear in my example? It explicitly shows that dominant must occupy at least one of the shown positions.

Answer (score -1):

To say the truth I haven't got any of answers here, but they gave an idea how to solve the problem. Based on the answer by @MBo as was mentioned, you use quick selection for an every 10th element, but you use not a simple quick selection, but the quick selection based on 3-way quick sort. You not just place every 10th element on its place, but also all elements that are equal to it.
And after one iteration is enough to count all elements that have more than 9 duplicates.

Comment: This isn’t an answer, more like a comment

Comment: Will strongly disagree that this is not an answer. In the question you've asked about ideas how to solve this problem. So the idea is to take the method that was discussed in the series of lessons where this question is originally asked. Even the exact method is named. I agree that that's not a solution, but this is for sure an answer. Hope it will help somebody) And thats a comment))))

Answer (score -1):

I decided this question with Dijkstra's approach to solve DNF problem.
Please see my emplementation below. May be it will be interest and useful to somebody.

```
public void dCount(Comparable[] arr) {
    dCount(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}
private void dCount(Comparable[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo >= hi) return;
    int curr = lo;
    int lt = lo;
    int rt = hi;
    Comparable pivot = arr[lo];

    while (curr <= rt) { // 3-way qSort main cycle
        if (less(arr[curr], pivot))
            swap(arr, curr++, lt++);
        else if (less(pivot, arr[curr]))
            swap(arr, curr, rt--);
        else curr++;
    }
    int count = curr - lt;
    if (count > arr.length / 10) { // you can change count value if it needs (n / 3, n / 2... just change 10 to your number)           
        System.out.printf("%s repeats %d times\n", arr[lt], count);
    }
    dCount(arr, lo, lt -1); // recur call for the left side from the pivot equal range
    dCount(arr, rt + 1, hi); // recur call for the right side from the pivot equal range
}
private static boolean less(Comparable a, Comparable b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) < 0;
}
private static void swap(Comparable[] arr, int i, int j) {
    Comparable swap = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = swap;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your code and provide a time complexity analysis?

Comment: I got idea from princeton quicksort lecture https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr18/cos226/lectures/23Quicksort.pdf

Comment: please look at pages 31-40. I just entered a variable count. You can see that when we find duplicate of pivot - there are duplicates between of curr and lt pointers. We just compare count with array length / 10.
Time complexity analysis you can find on page 40 of above pdf. When we say about many duplicate keys are in the array we can assume time compexity as O(n). I tried to find a proof of that - it turned out to be difficult for me.

Comment: A link is not an explanation. At Stackoverflow, self contained answers are preferred since links add little value and can be found by Google search.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Thank you for you explanation. It's very useful for me since that was my first steps at Stackoverflow. I'll keep it in mind in future.